# Combine integer and data type name? Not sure how to explain

Tags: java

EDIT for basic example:

Let's say I have 3 strings called name1, name2, name3.

If I were to create a method such as:

```
public void changeName(int number) {
    name + number = "Joe"
}
```

so if I do changeName(1) it would change name1 to Joe.
changeName(2) would change name2 to Joe.

Somehow combine the string name plus the number to reach the certain name I want.
Sorry for asking a dumb question I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: You might want to try rephrasing your question without any technical information (e.g. skip all the programmer jargon). Just telling us what you're trying to do in plain language may clarify (both for yourself and us) the functionality that you're trying to implement. TLDR: What do you want to happen when the user clicks a slot?

Comment: Just to add to @MarsAtomic comment, that doesn't mean you should not provide what have you tried to accomplish your goal, this is, providing the relevant code to know your effort and help you on that basis.

Comment: I wonder how you would "click a slot", when a "slot" is a Java class or, maybe, a variable. slot1_1 doesn't occur elsewhere. We don't see a JLabel. Then "slot" (which is a class name) is used as a method, with an argument that's always 1. - Nothing makes sense.

Comment: Use an array of slots rather than eight different slot variables? BTW, names of classes should start with an uppercase letter. Please follow the conventions.

Comment: Use an array or list

Comment: Are name1, name2, and name3 local variables?

Comment: Why "Joe"? Why not "Fred"?

Answer (score 0):

Put variables on a map/dictionary instead of trying to manipulate variables by name .

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name1", "someVal");
```

then the method to change the name will become :

```
public void changeName(int number) {
    map.put( name + number ) = "Joe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Java. Java doesn't build variable names dynamically. But an array would do more or less the same thing for you.

```
String[] names = new String[3];

public void changeName(int number) {
    names[ number - 1 ] = "Joe";
}
```

The reason for the `number-1` is that array indexes start from zero in Java, so you can think of it as if it was `name0`,`name1`,`name2` etc.

So if you have several similar objects which you have to access by an index number, use an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an array and another parameter for your intention to make sense:

```
String[] names = new String[3];

public void changeName(int number, String name) {
    names[number - 1] = name;
}
```

Comment: What's with the `--i`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic it decrements `i` before using it as the index, so a parameter of 1 gets stored at index 0, which is the first position in the array because java arrays are zero based. Parameter 2 gets stored at 1, etc

Comment: Well, first, it's doing something unnecessary because it stores the decremented value back in i, which you will never use. Second, i is not the name of a parameter at all.